# if $\sin(x)=\frac{1}{3}$ and $\sec(y)=\frac{5}{4} $, what is $\sin(x+y)?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

if $\sin(x)=\frac{1}{3}$ and $\sec(y)=\frac{5}{4} $, what is $\sin(x+y)?$

Here is my thought process:

the identity says:

$\sin(x+y)=\sin(x)\cos(y)+\cos(x)\sin(y)$

We know $\sin(x)=1/3$ and $\sec(y)=\frac{1}{\cos(y)} = \frac{4}{5}$, so

$\sin(x+y)=\frac{1}{3}\times\frac{4}{5}+\cos(x)\sin(y)$

But I'm stuck here because I don't know how to find $\cos(x)$ or $\sin(y)$

Comment: Please consider using \sin and \cos in "Math mode" to get $\sin$ and $\cos$ instead of simply sin and cos which give $sin$ and $cos$.

Comment: This problem is [badly posed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4647685).  There is no solution as it is written.  This problem comes from James Stewart's verification tests --- I believe it appears at least in the 6th edition.  The problem restricts the angle to be between $0$ and $\pi/2$.

Answer (score 2):

Draw a right triangle for each angle, label the known sides, then find the missing side. The unknown ratio should be obvious.

[image]

Note that the Pythagorean theorem and the Pythagorean identity are equivalent to one another.
$$\text{opposite}^2+\text{adjacent}^2 = \text{hypotenuse}^2$$
$$\frac{\text{opposite}^2+\text{adjacent}^2}{\text{hypotenuse}^2} = \frac{\text{hypotenuse}^2}{\text{hypotenuse}^2}$$
$$\bigg(\frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{hypotenuse}}\bigg)^2 + \bigg(\frac{\text{adjacent}}{\text{hypotenuse}}\bigg)^2=\bigg( \frac{\text{hypotenuse}}{\text{hypotenuse}}\bigg)^2$$
$$\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1^2$$
[image]

Lastly, try to derive the *sum of angles formula* by referring to the last diagram. Hint: use the *law of sines*.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have started off well. To get the values of $\cos x$ and $\sin y$, you should use the identity

$$\sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta \equiv 1$$

**I will show you how to find** $\cos x$.

**You can use the same method to find $\sin y$ yourself.**

For example, if $\sin x = \frac{1}{3}$ then we have

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sin^2 x + \cos^2x &\equiv& 1 \\ \\
\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{\! 2} + \cos^2x &=& 1 \\ \\
\frac{1}{9} + \cos^2x &=& 1 \\ \\
\cos^2x &=& \frac{8}{9} \\ \\
\cos x&=& \pm\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{2}
\end{eqnarray*}

Next you need to decide on the $\pm$. [Looking at the graph of $y=\cos x$](https://www.bbc.co.uk/staticarchive/95aa18261dea560a856fe4ff4ae9f5308f82ba20.gif) we see that $\cos x > 0$ if $0^{\circ} \le x < 90^{\circ}$ or $270^{\circ} < x \le 360^{\circ}$. So, for example: if we know that $x$ is acute then
$$\cos x = +\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{2}$$

If we know that $x$ is obtuse then
$$\cos x = -\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{2}$$

If $x$ is reflex and less that $270^{\circ}$ then 
$$\cos x = +\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{2}$$

If $x$ is reflex and more than $270^{\circ}$ then
$$\cos x = -\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{2}$$

[The same is true modulo $360^{\circ}$](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).

Comment: The sine of $x$ is positive, which only ocurrs in the first and second quadrant, but that's where cossine is positive, so $\cos x$ is positive.  However, for the sine of $y$, I seem to be in trouble.  The cossine of $y$ is positive, which occurs in the first and fourth quadrant. The sine of $y$ is positive in the first, but negative in the fourth.  So I cannot decide yet.  Any advice?