# How can I tell the sign of $\sin y$ in this linked problem?

Tags: trigonometry

**Update**.  As the accepted answer explains --- there is no solution to this problem.  The original problem comes from James Stewart's verification tests in his Calculus textbook --- I believe it appears at least in the 6th edition.  The original problem restricts the angle to be between $0$ and $\pi/2$.

---

I'm struggling with [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1422492).  The problem is: if $\sin(x)=\frac{1}{3}$ and $\sec(y)=\frac{5}{4}$, what is $\sin(x+y)?$  No problem with the identity: $\sin(x+y)=\sin(x)\cos(y)+\cos(x)\sin(y)$.  So the problem is solved if we compute $\cos x$ and $\sin y$.  It looks like I computed $\cos x$: using Pythagoras on the unit circle, we get

$$\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^2 + \cos^2 x = 1,$$

which implies $\cos x = \pm \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}$.  The sine of $x$ is positive, which can only happen in the first and second quadrant, where cosine is positive, so $\cos x = \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}$.

But I could not apply the same reasoning to discover $\sin y$.  Here's why.  The cosine of $y$ is positive, which only occurs in the first and fourth quadrant, that is, $y \in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}] \cup [\frac{3\pi}{2}, 2\pi] = [-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}]$.  We want the sine of $y$, but the $\sin y$ is positive in the first quadrant and it's negative in the fourth.  So I cannot tell.

Comment: In the second quadrant, cosine is negative, so $\cos x$ might be $-\frac{2\sqrt 2}{3}$.

Comment: "The sine of $x$ is positive, which can only happen in the first and second quadrant, **where cosine is positive**" - this part is wrong

Comment: You're right --- cossine is negative on the second quadrant. Okay, this means I cannot even get $\cos x$ as I thought.  In other words, I'm not seeing how to deduce the sign of $\cos x$ and $\sin y$.

Comment: Not having a unique solution is different from not having a solution.

Comment: You're right.  But then I'd say the only way to solve the problem is to give out all possibilities for $\sin(x + y)$, right?  There's not only one.  It would seem incomplete if we give one solution and neglect the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is badly posed. There are four possible values of $\sin(x+y)$, depending on whether $\sin y$ and $\cos x$ are positive or negative.

Comment: Which one is badly posed?  The problem originally or my presentation of it?  Why is it badly posed?  Right, there are four possible values of $sin(x + y$.  I must somehow eliminate the possibilities that cannot happen, but when I get to investigate $sin y$, I don't see a way out.  (In fact, I did not calculate $\cos x$ correctly either.)

Comment: The problem is badly posed because there _is_ no way out. The question in your link is also badly posed.

Comment: You're totally right.  (I'm glad I couldn't solve it!)  This problem is properly written in James Stewart's verification tests, before chapter 1, on his Calculus text--- I believe it appears at least in the 6th edition.  The problem restricts the angle to be between $0$ and $\pi/2$.  (I won't fix the question.  But I'll update it.)  I warned the original poster with a comment.